# Coprime Subsets

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose I have numbers 1 to N and I want to divide them into subsets based on following criteria:

1. Each number can be present in only 1 subset.
2. The elements of the subsets must be mutually coprime.
3. Minimizing the total number of subsets.

My approach to it is by finding all primes up to N using Sieve of Eratosthenes and then dividing them accordingly in subsets. For example for N=5, I can have two subsets at minimum {1,2,3,5} and {4}. But I am unsure how to distribute the elements in subsets so that each subset has mutually coprime elements. Here's my approach stepwise:

1. Set 1: {all primes up to N}
2. Set 2 onwards: {$2^k,3^k,5^k...p^k$} where p is a prime and $p^k < N$. For different values of k, we can form different sets till $2^k< N$.
   So the sets will be like {$2^2,3^2,5^2,...p^2$} , {$2^3,3^3,5^3,...p^3$}... till {$2^k$}.
3. Rest of the elements

The problem is how to divide elements in step 3 to be mutually coprime in the subsets Can someone suggest a better approach on how to implement it and flaws in my logic?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61024026/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3608999/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No two even numbers are coprime, so the number of subsets required is at least $\left\lfloor \frac{N}2\right\rfloor$. In fact, for $N>1$ this can be done with exactly $\left\lfloor \frac{N}2\right\rfloor$ subsets because $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime.

For example $1...11$ can be partitioned as $(1,2,3)(4,5)(6,7)(8,9)(10,11)$